# Remove MISS from username in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query in which I want to remove the **MISS**, **MR** type of things from the `user_name`

I tried with below query

```
SELECT   0 user_id, '--- Select ---' user_name
FROM DUAL
UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT user_id, LTRIM (user_name) user_name
       FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_user_det_v
   ORDER BY user_name
```

but still it is not working for me.

Here is the screenshot

[image: img]

Comment: Oracle Corporation owns MySQL Server but it's an entirely different product than their flagship Oracle Database. I've removed the question tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several possible prefixes you want to delete, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(user_name, '^(MISS|MS\.|MS|MRS\.|MRS|MR\.|MR)\s*', '') as user_name
```

`^` anchors the search at the beginning of the string, `(...|...|...)` means match any of the choices in parentheses, and `\s` is a single space; `\s*` means zero or more consecutive spaces. All that is deleted from the beginning of each string. The dot `.` must be escaped with backspace (otherwise it stands for "any single character").

If you need case-insensitive matching, if you may also have `Miss` in addition to `MISS`, use the full syntax of `regexp_replace`.

Edit: one more thing... the alternatives are tried one by one, from left to right, and the first match is used. So `MS\.` should appear before `MS`, otherwise `MS` (without a dot) will match `MS` in `MS. SMITH` and this will leave the dot and the space at the beginning of the string. I had to correct that in the solution.

Comment: here one thing, my `--- Select ---` is not coming on top with respect to my query

Comment: I don't understand. What does that mean?

Comment: my `--select--` should come on top. but currently it is coming like this https://s4.postimg.org/rn8g3yol9/image.png

Comment: What does that have to do with removing MISS from the beginning of the string? This is a different, unrelated question, regarding ORDER BY; if you have a question about it, post it separately.

Comment: If you want to remove an optional full-stop you can just make it optional once: `^(MISS|MS|MRS|MR)\.?\s*`.

Comment: @Ben - that works in this case, because we assume "MISS." is not a legitimate name. (It is NOT a legitimate prefix either, but we assume if there is ever a "MISS." that is a mistake.) In the general case though, if the period may only follow some of the options, but not all of them, this solution wouldn't work - you would have to write it the way I did. (By the way, that was the first way I wrote it, and then I changed it exactly for this reason.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) function like

```
REPLACE(user_name,'MISS','') as user_name
```

Comment: i have, `miss`, `mr`, `mrs`. multiple things here. how can I use that all ?

Comment: @stack, but those info missing from your question. BTW, you can still replace them all recursively.

Comment: i know, but I mentioned two miss and mr. yes let me know how to use that ?

Comment: @stack, like `REPLACE(REPLACE(user_name,'MISS',''),'MR',''))`

Comment: here one thing, my `--- Select ---` is not coming on top with respect to my query

Answer (score 0):

if you have column struct like (mr|mrs|other)/**space**/username you can try this

```
with users(user_name) as 
              (select 'mr user name1' from dual union all 
               select 'miss username2 ' from dual union all
               select 'other username 3' from dual )

select substr(user_name,instr(user_name,' ')+1) real_username from users
```

output

```
REAL_USERNAME  
----------------
user name1       
username2        
username 3
```

it `substr` from first founded space symbol

in your query

```
SELECT   0 user_id, '--- Select ---' user_name
FROM DUAL
UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT user_id, substr(user_name,instr(user_name,' ')+1) user_name
       FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_user_det_v
   ORDER BY user_name
```

if you want --- Select--- start from top you can:

```
select user_id, user_name
from (

    SELECT   0 user_id, '--- Select ---' user_name, 1 order_by
FROM DUAL
UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT user_id, substr(user_name,instr(user_name,' ')+1) user_name, 2 order_by
       FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_user_det_v
) 
   ORDER BY order_by, user_name
```

Comment: You are hardcoding all the names starting with `us`? That doesn't match the OP's sample data.

Comment: lol then you should see why this solution doesn't work. "other username 3" does not begin with MISS or MR etc. - you just deleted "other" which is probably part of the name, not a prefix.

Comment: in OP example all rows start from something word before real_username.

Comment: Answering the unrelated question about order... you don't need to add a column to `order by`, you can just have a `case` expression in the `order by` clause itself. I will wait for OP to ask this separately though, since it has absolutely nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: @mathguy, many answers may be, i think like so,but you thinking another.i'am glad that you have many attention to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121931/discussion-between-mathguy-and--).